# Libvirt KVM networking, how to make guest accessible from outside with public IP?

Tags: networking, routing, centos-7, linux-kvm, libvirt

Good afternoon, I've ordered dedicated server CentOS 7 from ISP. Also got 10 public IP addresses.
Have following situation:
Dedicated server IP is:149.XX.XXX.29/24

## Default gateway: 149.XX.XXX.1

Other IP addresses:
149.XX.XXX.65/24
149.XX.XXX.66/24
149.XX.XXX.68/24
149.XX.XXX.70/24
......
149.XX.XXX.73/24

## Default gateway is same 149.XX.XXX.1

I've installed Libvirt KVM setup completed successfully, created new VM, NAT networking and Bridged networking works fine.
Using bridged networking:
Meaning - bridged physical ethernet.
Now I can assign one if public IPs to my VM and access internet from this last.
But - I cannot access my VM from outside.
Can anyone explain my how to arrange routing to access my VM from outside pinging assigned public IP.
for now firewall is turned off and selinux is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, maybe nobody knows how to access guests but I found very pure solution:

- Disable SELinux
- Disable Firewall

That worked, now I've to research two things:

- How to configure firewall to guest access

  **And**
- How to manage SELinux for Libvirt (if it's possible)

**UPDATE**

Now firewall works fine, just need to disable SELinux.